# IIS express still queuing concurrent requests even with sessions disabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I'm trying to manually test concurrent requests using IIS express.  Even if I open up 40 tabs, the requests run my action methods 1 at a time.

I've disabled session state so that request queuing should not happen.

How can I get IIS express to run all requests concurrently??  I'm on Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Did you decorate your controller with: `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` ?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Mention the "Edition" as well - Starter, Basic etc.